# Javascript Multi-select plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using the following plugin [Chosen Plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#selected-and-disabled-support) but I don't know why it is not working. Here is my following code and what it is showing.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chosen.jquery.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="chosen.jquery.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">

 $(".chosen-select").chosen();

</script>

</head>

<body>

    <select style="width:350px;" multiple class="chosen-select">

        <option value=""></option>

<option value="1">Option 1</option>

<option value="2">Option 2</option>

<option value="3">Option 3</option>

<option value="4">Option 4</option>

<option value="5">Option 5</option>

<option value="6">Option 6</option>

<option value="7">Option 7</option>

<option value="8">Option 8</option>

<option value="9">Option 9</option>

<option value="10">Option 10</option>

</select>

</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `chosen` plugin before DOM content is loaded. Move the following code at the bottom of body and you're good to go

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(".chosen-select").chosen();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `$(".chosen-select").chosen();` after the `select` element, or run it when ready

```
$(function() {
  $(".chosen-select").chosen();
});
```